# How to install APC on a vagrant box running Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apc, chef-infra, vagrant

In my "Vagrant" file I have this line:

```
chef.add_recipe("php::module_apc")
```

But it gives me this error:

```
[2013-01-11T22:14:53+00:00] INFO: Processing package[php-apc] action install (php::module_apc line 34)
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[php-apc]'
================================================================================
Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
apt-get -q -y install php-apc=3.1.7-1 returned 100, expected 0

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/php/recipes/module_apc.rb

 33: when "debian"
 34:   package "php-apc" do
 35:     action :install
 36:   end
 37: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/php/recipes/module_apc.rb:34:in `from_file'

package("php-apc") do
  retry_delay 2
  retries 0
  recipe_name "module_apc"
  action [:install]
  cookbook_name :php
  package_name "php-apc"
end
[2013-01-11T22:14:53+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-01-11T22:14:53+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-01-11T22:14:53+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-01-11T22:14:53+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[php-apc] (php::module_apc line 34) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: apt-get -q -y install php-apc=3.1.7-1 returned 100, expected 0
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

I'm also running this before:

```
chef.add_recipe("apt")
```

But it's no help either.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Btw, I'm using all cookbooks from OpsCode:
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/

Comment: I think you should try http://serverfault.com/.  This website is more about programming.

Comment: Ah, probably. Can I move it somehow?

Comment: Try logging in to vagrant machine and running `apt-get -q -y install php-apc=3.1.7-1`. Then you will see what the exact error message is.

Comment: Ye, it says:
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php-apc : Depends: phpapi-20090626
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
Seems there's no APC package for PHP 5.4 yet?!

Comment: Seems like Ubuntu12.04 does not have phpapi-20090626 package. See http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/nathan-renniewaldock_ppa/precise/main/base/php-apc Try adding ppa and installing 3.1.13-1 version.

Answer (score 2):

In `module_apc.rb` change;

```
apt-get install php-apc
```

... to:

```
apt-get install php5-apc
```